# Promise chain of catchs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have this scenario:

### controller.ts

```
methodA(): void {
    myServive.someMethod()
    .then( () => console.log("then") )
    .catch( e => {
        console.log("catch");
    });
}
```

### service.ts

```
someMethod(): ng:IPromise<void> {

    const deferred = this.$q.defer<void>();

    return this.OtherService.otherMethod()
    .catch ( e => {
        deferred.reject(reason);
    }
}
```

### otherservice.ts

```
otherMethod(): ng.IPromise<any> {
    return this.HttpService.get(url);
}
```

Test:

- The otherMethod (otherService.ts) is getting an error from the HttpService.
- The catch in someMethod (service.ts) is been executed.

Why, in the controller.ts, the **then** block is been executed?

Comment: From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch): "The Promise returned by catch() is rejected if onRejected throws an error or returns a Promise which is itself rejected; otherwise, it is resolved."

Answer (score 1):

The `catch` is executed **if some previous `then` (or `catch`) throws an error**. If no errors, the code will execute the next `then` statement.

So you have this code:

```
methodA(): void {
    myServive.someMethod()
    .then( () => console.log("then") )
    .catch( e => {
        console.log("catch"); // No errors thrown, so the code will continue in the next then
    });
}
```

So you can throw an error inside the `catch`. The code will continue to the next catch:

```
methodA(): void {
    myServive.someMethod()
    .then( () => console.log("then") )
    .catch( e => {
        console.log("catch");
        throw new Error(e) // Some error happened! The code will continue in the next catch
    });
}
```

Comment: Tks Rashomon! The throw should be in the service.ts, right? Thus, I can execute the catch block on the controller.ts. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Or you can just remove the entire catch. For each error thrown, one catch will be executed

Answer (score 0):

> Why, in the controller.ts, the then block is been executed?

because you caught the error and returned undefined in `service.ts`

It looks like you should just get rid of the catch/defer entirely in `service.ts` if you don't plan on handling any errors in there.

EDIT: If you want the catch to be handled in the controller, then just remove all the stuff from `service.ts` and just let do:

```
// service.ts
someMethod(): ng:IPromise<void> {
    return this.OtherService.otherMethod()
}
```

If you want to handle the catch in `service.ts` **AND** in the controller, then rethrow the error (or a new one):

```
// service.ts
someMethod(): ng:IPromise<void> {

    const deferred = this.$q.defer<void>();

    return this.OtherService.otherMethod()
    .catch ( e => {
        // you can either do:
        // throw e
        // which rethrows the same error (same as not having a catch in here at all)
        // or you can handle the error and throw a new one like:
        //
        // ...some error handling code
        // throw new Error('my new error');
    });
}
```

No matter which you choose, you don't need a deferred.

Comment: Adam, how to solve it? SHould we put "return deferred.reject(reason)" ?

Comment: @LucianoBorges solve what? What do you want to happen?